# Moving emails in outlook between folders while inputing the subject list, and restrictring certain conditions

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm trying to search "All Outlook Items" and then find emails based on the subject list I input into the code. Once the email is found, it is moved to another folder and marked as "Task Complete" (The green check in the emails).

However, I'm having a couple of errors when trying to run the code. If anyone can guide me it'd be amazing.

Here's the code:

```
import win32com.client 


Email = 'johndoe@gmail.com'
subjects = input("Enter a list of subjects separated by commas: ").split(",")
MoveToFolder = "folder1"
Iter_Folder = "folder2"

def find_and_download_case_number_related_emails():

    Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    Outlook_Location = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Lookin_Folder = Outlook_Location.Folders[Email].Folders[Iter_Folder]
    Out_MoveToFolder = Outlook_Location.Folders[Email].Folders[MoveToFolder]

    for message in Lookin_Folder:
        if message.TaskCompleted:
            continue
        for message in Lookin_Folder:
            if message.Subject in subjects:
                message.Move(Out_MoveToFolder)

    for message in Out_MoveToFolder:
        message.MarkAsTaskCompleted()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_and_download_case_number_related_emails()
```

and here's the error I'm getting at the moment:

```
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.Items. Did you mean: 'Item'?
```

Comment: Where is your inbox folder?

Comment: So I made a couple of changes to the code, and think it's almost ready to go. I'm not sure how to implement the restriction on an email as of yet.

Comment: see example restriction https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091622/4539709

Comment: and how to loop on folders https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211042/4539709

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code contains a wrong property call:

```
outlook.Folders.Items.Restrict
```

The `Folders` class doesn't provide the `Items` property. You need to get a `Folder` instance and only then use `Items` property.

I'd suggest using the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Inbox folder for the user who is currently logged on.

To understand how the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods work in Outlook you may take a look at the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: The thing is, I need the code to go through all of the folders

Comment: So I made some changes to the code, and I think it's almost ready to go. However I'm not sure how to include a restriction to a specific email.

Comment: I've added some links to read about the Restrict or Find/FindNext methods.