# In python, is there a way to add message items we get from outlook. I'm trying to loop all items at once. I think I am missing something here

Tags: python, outlook

```
inbox1 = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("a").folders("b").folders("c1")
inbox2 = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("a").folders("b").folders("c2")

messages = # how to add inbox1.Items and inbox2.items
```

As said in the title, when I loop through messages I want to loop through all the emails in c1 and c2 folder. I don't know what I should write for -> *messages* variable.

I tried doing an append but I sort of knew before hand it wouldn't work.

Edit : win32com.client.CDispatch  This is the datatype for the variable - message

Comment: Is `inbox1.Items` a list?  Try `messages = inbox1.Items + inbox2.Items`

Comment: What outlook API are you using? Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: @JonSG I can't use the + operator. The variable type for message is win32com.client.CDispatch

Comment: @Barmar win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier if you used an Outlook-specific API instead of win32.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211042/4539709

Comment: is it 2 different inboxes? like shared inbox

Comment: @0m3r Its the same inbox with different subfolders in it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve - you can loop through the messages in one folder, then in another folder. Or (the worst alternative) you can create an array large enough to contain messages from both folders, add them to the array, then loop through the resulting array.

Either way, it is a pretty bad idea - never loop through all items in a folder. If you need to find a particular item, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. If you need data from **all** messages, retrieve the data using `MAPIFolder.GetTable`